# List the department name and the number of employees in each department

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query 4.    List the department name and the number of employees (including contractors) in each department.

```
select Departments_Name AS "Department", Num_of_employ AS "Number of Employees"
from departments, employee_id 
group by Departments_Name, Num_of_employ 
order by Departments_Name
offset 0 rows fetch first 12 rows only;
```

I know I have to use aggregate functions however whenever this is executed, The Departments_Name of 'Accounting' repeats in the output

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help me?

[image: This is my table structure]

Code run

[image: this is the result I get when I use query you provided for me]

Comment: I note you have been advised on previous questions to use the correct join syntax instead of this old style implicit join. There is a good reason for that advice, you are much more likely to get the results you desire, or an error if you make a mistake - whereas your query won't be giving you what you want, but won't be giving you an error either.

Comment: my apologies. I'll be sure to engage more from now on

Comment: 1) Please add table structures and results as formatted text, not images. 2) The table structure you have shown does not show enough info for us to know what you want to join on. 3) You appear to have different spellings for the same department - You can't expect a query to automatically correct spelling mistakes.

Comment: I don't know how to structure the table with text.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a clever developer such as yourself can work that out :)

Comment: As you can see, we really do want to help you solve the problem, but you need to work with us and answer the questions and provide the additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually need information from your `employee_id` table then you need to join it on using your foreign key. That said I can't see that you are using it. Also use *proper* join syntax not the old style implicit join you were attempting to use. At the moment you will be getting a duplicate department row per employee.

Then depending on whether you store `Num_of_employ` or whether you are trying to calculate it, either way you don't want to `group by`. You may want to sum it, but that doesn't make sense unless you have multiple entries per department.

```
select D.Departments_Name as "Department", sum(D.Num_of_employ) as "Number of employees"
from dbo.departments D
-- Do you actually need to join this on? You don't appear to be using it.
-- inner join dbo.employee_id E on E.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentId
group by D.Departments_Name
order by D.Departments_Name
offset 0 rows fetch first 12 rows only;
```

Maybe you are attempting to `count` the staff e.g.

```
select D.Departments_Name as "Department", count(*) as "Number of employees"
from dbo.departments D
inner join dbo.employee_id E on E.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentId
group by D.Departments_Name
order by D.Departments_Name
offset 0 rows fetch first 12 rows only;
```

Comment: For the inner join, I don't have DepartmentID just Departments_Name so would I take out E.DepartmentId and instead of D.DepartmentId would I put D.Departments_Name? So it would read inner join dbo.employee_id E on D.Departments_name

Comment: Add your table structures to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the query according to the question you have asked, let me know if you find it useful

Here employee_status is column which as data like Contractual/Permanent

```
select employee_department as "Department", count(*) as "Number of employees",employee_status
from departments 
group by Departments_Name,employee_status
order by Departments_Name 
offset 0 rows fetch first 12 rows only;
```

Comment: Can you share your table structure, if this is not useful. @Dale

Comment: I just added the table structure

Comment: Can you add the column in contractors table as well to be more clear.

Comment: Where are you getting `employee_status` status from? OP makes no mention of it?

Comment: employee_status  that is an assumption,  correct answer can only be given if we have the right table structure. So I asked him to  share the details again as it doesn't give us clear picture.